# Bad File descriptor

Tags: c, pipe, unix

Does  anyone see a problem with this, its not working saying bad file descriptor not sure why?

```
pipe(pipefd[0]);
if ((opid = fork()) == 0) {
     dup2(pipefd[0][1],1);/*send to output*/
     close(pipefd[0][0]);
     close(pipefd[0][1]);
     execlp("ls","ls","-al",NULL);
}

 if((cpid = fork())==0){
   dup2(pipefd[0][1],0);/*read from input*/
   close(pipefd[0][0]);
   close(pipefd[1][1]);
   execlp("grep","grep",".bak",NULL);
}

  close(pipefd[0][0]);
  close(pipefd[0][1]);
```

Comment: What's the declaration for pipefd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I'm guessing pipefd is defined as:

```
int pipefd[2][2];
```

Now, when you do:

```
pipe(pipefd[0])
```

This only populates `pipefd[0][0]` and `pipefd[0][1]`.

So when you do:

```
# Bad descriptor
close(pipefd[1][1]);
```

you are referencing random junk (you never set `pipefd[1][0]` or `pipefd[1][1]`).

From the code shown, I can't see why you aren't just doing:

```
int pipefd[2];
pipe(pipefd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexes in the second block look suspect.