# Why do I get a close: Bad file descriptor error for this fork pipe c program?

Tags: c, process, fork, pipe, stdin

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int count = 2;


    int pid, status;
    int fd[count][2];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (pipe(fd[i]) != 0) {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            if (close(fd[i][1]) != 0) {
                perror("close");
                exit(1);
            } 
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
                close(fd[j][1]);
            }
            char w[MAXWORD];
        int result;
            result = read(fd[i][0], w, MAXWORD);
        w[result-1] = '\0';
            printf("child %s\n" w);
            if (result == -1) {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
            }
            exit(0);
        } else {
            if (close(fd[i][0]) != 0) {
                perror("close");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    while (1) {
        char word[MAXWORD]; int c;
        c = read(STDIN_FILENO, word, MAXWORD);
        if (c == 0) {
                break;
        }
        word[c-1] = '\0';
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
                write(fd[i][1], word, strlen(word)+1);
        }


        for (i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
                if (close(fd[i][1]) != 0) {
                perror("close");
                exit(1);
                }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                wait(&status);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code reads in a loop a word that user inputs until control+d is hit. That word is sent to the pipe to two child processes. Both of them print the word. If I take out the while (1) statment then it works fine. The problem is I get this error when I enter a word the second time when I keep the while 1 loop:

```
$ query
hello
child hello
child hello
hello
close: Bad file descriptor
```

Please I really need help because I really can't figure why it's doing this. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bad File descriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597213/bad-file-descriptor)

Comment: I don't think that applies to me. I'm piping both values of i in a for loop.

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this one. Maybe some details change, but they all seems duplicate to me. I've just casted a vote. We will see if I'm right.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of 'Bad file descriptor'...it is loosely related, but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues

1) Each child only reads once, echoes, and then exits but your while loop appears to want to send multiple words to each child (this isn't what caused the issue though)

2) In the main while loop you read the word, write it to each child and then close the file descriptors you write to.  The second time through the loop all your descriptors are closed so the close call fails.  The write calls also failed but, because you don't check the return value, you didn't realize it.

Comment: For 1) you said each child only reads once. How do I make it read multiple times? For 2) do I put the close statements outside the while loop?

Comment: Like the write, the read has to be in a loop (until the read fails)

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. But 2) I can't figure out because if I leave out the close statements the program stops running when I enter a second word. Any tips?

Comment: Move the close and the wait statements outside the while loop.  Figure out some way of indicating "out of input" to exit the while loop (eof would work).

Comment: To clarify - move the for loops and the close and wait statements outside the while loop.

Comment: Do you mean exit the while 1 loop. If so I've already set it up so that control+d would exit it because it takes input from stdin. I took the close and wait statement out of the loop. Nothing happens when I enter a word though. I type a word in and press enter then it waits for me type something else again. But none of my print statments are printing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26427/discussion-between-drc-and-shn)